# can we load a default message and current page url on fb messenger button?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, facebook

i am starting a website which provides ayurvedic home made solutions to treat the diseases on which i have different pages with different home based remedies.

i have a piece of code which has a button of "this tip was helpful for me"  which opens admin fb messenger where user can send direct message to fb page / web page admin..so i want to load a default message when the facebook messenger opens which says "thanks for this tip and it was really helpful for me " along with "current page url " and then user needs only to click send button without writing anything and it directly goes to admin messenger.

here is the code

```
<html>
<head>
<script> 
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '95100348886',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.6'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));  


</script>




</head>
<body>

 <div class="fb-messengermessageus" 
     messenger_app_id="95100348886" 
     page_id="xyz" 
     color="blue"
     size="large">
</div>

<a href="https://m.me/xyz">
Message us on Facebook
 </a>


</body>


</html>
```

replace xyz with facebook page name .

thanks in advance ..

Comment: prefilling messages is not allowed. users need to write them on their own.

Comment: can we do that with facebook send dialog button??

Comment: The Send-to-Messenger Plugin allows you to pass in custom data of up to 250 characters ...